# 2x3 Mixed Factorial Design or Pre-Post Design?

Tags: manova, pre-post-comparison

I am conducting a study for a MSc., and was told by my supervisor that my design would be a 2x3 mixed factorial design, but it seems like it might just be a pre and post test intervention design (I haven't done statistics since undergrad, and I really need brushing up, do I have it wrong completely?).

The study consists of:

A pre-test questionnaire

Then a two week intervention period of three groups (1 control, 2 experimental)

Then a post-test questionnaire.

Is my supervisor correct that this would be a 2x3 mixed factorial design? If so, she said I should use MANOVA. Thank you for any help that you might be able to provide!